# Problem when adding a column to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am adding a pandas series as a new column in a dataframe, and observed unattended changes.

```
X_test_col["Valor real ppna"]=y_test_pd
print (np.all(y_test_pd.iloc[0].dtype=="float64"), np.all(X_test_col["Valor real ppna"].dtype=="float64"))
```

Output

```
True True
```

Then

```
print (len(y_test_pd), len(X_test_col["Valor real ppna"]))
```

Output

```
9000 9000
```

And then

```
print (round(X_test_col["Valor real ppna"].count()))
```

Output

```
256
```

Finally

```
print (round(y_test_pd.count()))
```

Output:

```
ppna (kg/ha.dia)    9000
dtype: int64
```

As you can see the column

```
 X_test_col["Valor real ppna"]
```

assigned as a new 
column effectively appears as having the same length and the same dtypes as the original series.
BUT when I try to use the values, it appears that they are 256 and NOT 9000 as I expected.
I have been working with this problem for some hours, trying to assign the dtype and so on, and so on,  and I need some help.
What should I do to correctly assign the 9000 values to the new dataframe column?
FYI: the y_test_pd comes from the sklearn train_test_split() function.

In order to explain better, I have passed the dataframes to excel.
This is the original dataset:

[image: Original dataset]

This is the column to add

[image]

And this is the desired output:

[image]

Comment: Hi Hermes, can you post 5 rows of your input data and 5 rows of your expected data? please read [mcve]

Comment: Adding the images of the expected output I realize that, just in case, I can do it in excel...

Comment: is `y_test_pd` a dataframe or series?

Comment: type(y_test_pd) --> pandas.core.frame.DataFrame